# multiple select in graphql query

Tags: graphql

I am started learn graphql and use SpaceX api (https://api.spacex.land/graphql/)
I have theese query:

```
{
  shipsResult(
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0,
    find: {
      type: "Cargo",
      home_port: "Port Canaveral"
    }) {
    result {
      totalCount
    }
    data {
      id
      name
      type
      home_port
    }
  }
}
```

I need select more than one value in home_port parameter, like array ["Port Canaveral", "Port of Los Angeles"]

What i shall do?